# Is there a general method to estimate the parameter of a Poisson distribution numerically using MLE in R?

Tags: r, distributions, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Assuming for the phishing values to come from a Poisson distribution of
> unknown lambda parameter, use the sample values to numerically estimate the parameter with
> the method of maximum likelihood, compare it with what you would have with the method of
> moments and with this estimate calculate the probability of having carried out more phishing than the first quartile of
> those present in test;

What I know is that for continuous random variables it is sufficient to rewrite in R the function of the specific distribution (or its logarithmic version), then through a for loop to multiply all the densities for each x_i belonging to the sample,

and for discrete distributions instead? if I were faced with a Bernoulli distribution (for example), or a Poisson distribution like the one in the exercise above, what should I do?

Note: this is not a duplicate of [MSE and MLE with Poisson distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262204/mse-and-mle-with-poisson-distribution), I'm my case I'm asking relative to R, more than a single theoretical explanation

Comment: in practice, in the discrete case do I have to make a production while in the continuous a summation?

Comment: Note that the maximum likelihood estimate for $\lambda$, the expectation of a Poisson distribution, is the sample mean.

Comment: I think I understand, so if I were to write in R it would be like this: `L_pois = function(lambda) (lambda^sum(k) / factorial(sum(k)))*exp(-lambda) lam = mean(k)
qpois(p=1/4, lambda = lam)`  (referring to the cited exercise)

Comment: I didn't do it, I understood that in the case of Poisson $\lambda = mean (sample)$, did I get it wrong?

Comment: You're right I didn't think about it, I'll try again

Comment: Ok, so same thing but for calculating the mean() numerically  `for (i in 1:length(k)) s = s+k[i]` 
 `lam = s/length(k)`

Comment: Your edit makes this sound like a pure programming question, which is not on topic here.